google analytics-api, java, how to declare OrderBys call RunReportRequest
String VIEW_ID = "0000000000";
String[] GA_METRICS = {"newUsers","activeUsers","totalUsers","addToCarts","cartToViewRate","checkouts","screenPageViews","totalPurchasers"};
List<Metric> metrics = new ArrayList<Metric>() {{
    for(String metricName : GA_METRICS) {
        add(Metric.newBuilder().setName(metricName).build());
    }               
}};
                        
List<OrderBy> orderBys = new ArrayList<OrderBy>() {{
    //how to declare Orderby...
    //i want to order by date asc
    add(OrderBy.newBuilder());
}};

RunReportRequest request = RunReportRequest.newBuilder().setProperty("properties/" + VIEW_ID)
        .addDimensions(Dimension.newBuilder().setName("date"))
        .addAllMetrics(metrics)
        .addAllOrderBys(orderBys)
        .addDateRanges(DateRange.newBuilder().setStartDate(dateRanges.get("startDate")).setEndDate(dateRanges.get("endDate"))).build();


I'd like to add an alignment in google-analytics api
However, we are unable to proceed because the released sample does not contain any details.
I searched the sample for ga4 and then checked it, but it was not applied to v1beta.
i can`t find any samples...about it
plz some help to me

What is the issue with what you have? is there an error

no i have no error... i want to know about sample....how to use orderby
old sample is
List orderBys= null;
if(params.get("fieldName")!=null) {
orderBys= new ArrayList<>();
OrderBy orderBy= new OrderBy().setFieldName((String) params.get("fieldName")).setSortOrder((String) params.get("sortOrder")).setOrderType((String)params.get("orderType"));
orderBys.add(orderBy);
}
===========
but it not apply on v1beta

did you check the docs for orderby

I found this example of orderBys:
https://github.com/googleanalytics/java-docs-samples/blob/main/google-analytics-data/src/main/java/com/google/analytics/data/samples/RunReportWithOrderingSample.java
static void sampleRunReportWithOrdering(String propertyId) throws Exception {
    // Initialize client that will be used to send requests. This client only needs to be created
    // once, and can be reused for multiple requests. After completing all of your requests, call
    // the "close" method on the client to safely clean up any remaining background resources.
    try (BetaAnalyticsDataClient analyticsData = BetaAnalyticsDataClient.create()) {
      RunReportRequest request =
          RunReportRequest.newBuilder()
              .setProperty("properties/" + propertyId)
              .addDimensions(Dimension.newBuilder().setName("date"))
              .addMetrics(Metric.newBuilder().setName("activeUsers"))
              .addMetrics(Metric.newBuilder().setName("newUsers"))
              .addMetrics(Metric.newBuilder().setName("totalRevenue"))
              .addDateRanges(DateRange.newBuilder().setStartDate("7daysAgo").setEndDate("today"))
              .addOrderBys(
                  OrderBy.newBuilder()
                      .setMetric(OrderBy.MetricOrderBy.newBuilder().setMetricName("totalRevenue"))
                      .setDesc(true))
              .build();

      // Make the request.
      RunReportResponse response = analyticsData.runReport(request);
      // Prints the response using a method in RunReportSample.java
      RunReportSample.printRunResponseResponse(response);
    }
  }
}

